# Zooming in and out removing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, 3d, zooming

I am using the `rotate3d` function to allow 3D rotation of a sphere through the mouse movement. However, when I rotate it, it zooms in and out. How can I disable this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
axis vis3d
```

to your figures before `rotate3d`.